# How do I say the expression 'half the glass/bowl'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am at a family dinner, and somebody offers me some soup, he wants to know how much do I want?

Can I say

> I want half the bowl(of soup).

or

> I want half the glass of lemonade.

Are these expressions idiomatic in this context?

Comment: Use _a_, not _the_: "I would like half a bowl of soup, and half a glass of lemonade." And don't forget to say "please" and "thank you." ;^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having been offered the soup, I might respond, "Half a bowl would be wonderful!  Thank you.", or perhaps "yes.  I will have half a bowl."